# White screen appear when open camera in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When open camera through zxing for qr code scan then in place of camera white screen appear while it scan the qr code correctly but it shows white screen?

Here is my code:

```
namespace Kefi.Controls
{
    public class CustomScanPage : ContentPage
    {
        ZXingScannerView zxing;
        public CustomScanPage() : base()
        {
            zxing = new ZXingScannerView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center

            };
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this,false);
            zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
                    zxing.IsScanning = false;
                    MessagingCenter.Send(result, "Scanresult");
                });
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };
        }
        protected  override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            zxing.Options.DelayBetweenAnalyzingFrames = 5;
            zxing.Options.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 5;
            zxing.IsScanning = true;

        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            zxing.IsScanning = false;
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some of the code that you are using to open the camera? Are you requesting permission from the user to use the camera?

Comment: yes camera permission is already allowed .

Comment: Is my answer working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You does not even add the `scannerView` to the contentPage,so it won't show. Add a simple `StackLayout` to hold the `scannerView` then set it to the `Content` of the `ContentPage`:

```
public CustomScanPage() 
        {

            zxing = new ZXingScannerView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Orange              
            };
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
                    zxing.IsScanning = false;
                    MessagingCenter.Send(result, "Scanresult");
                });

            var layout = new StackLayout();
            layout.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            layout.Children.Add(zxing);

            Content = zxing;
        }
```

Or you can custom the scannerView in xaml, see the blog here:  [scanning-generating-barcodes-zxing](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/scanning-generating-barcodes-zxing/)

Let me know if it works for you.